# Java type parameter confusion

Tags: java, shiro

I'm trying to implement the Apache Shiro [CacheManager interface](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/cache/CacheManager.html). Its only method has the following signature:

```
<K,V> Cache<K,V> getCache(String name) throws CacheException
```

It seems the leftmost `<K, V>` type parameter is effectively telling the compiler that K and V are "types." My question is this: How can I return an instance of that type? When I try the following code, Eclipse complains that K and V cannot be resolved to types:

```
public class ShiroGuavaCacheManager implements CacheManager
{
    private Cache<K, V> cache; // <--- The compiler complains here

    @Override
    public <K, V> Cache<K, V> getCache(String name) throws CacheException
    {
        return (cache != null) ? cache : new ShiroGuavaCache<K, V>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to define your own class that has a class member with parameterized types, you'll need to make the class parameterized, i.e. `public class ShiroGuavaCacheManager<K,V> implements CacheManager` ... In this case, you'll probably want to remove the first `<K,V>` from the declaration of `getCache`; you don't need to parameterize the method with the same parameters you're using for the class.  If you have no idea what I'm talking about and need an explanation about what generics are all about, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ShiroGuavaCacheManager` class, `K` and `V` are not defined. So if you wanted to make the `ShiroGuavaCacheManager` generic, it would be something like

```
public class ShiroGuavaCacheManager<K,V> implements CacheManager
{
    private Cache<K, V> cache; // without the class level K,V definitions, K and V are not known types

    @Override
    public Cache<K, V> getCache(String name) throws CacheException
    {
        return (cache != null) ? cache : new ShiroGuavaCache<K, V>();
    }
}
```

Then you could create a `new ShiroGuavaCacheManager<String,String>()` for example.

When you have a method that defines the types like the following (as in the original class):

```
public <K, V> Cache<K, V> getCache(String name)
```

This works because you decide what `K` and `V` are based on what you assign it to. So you could do

```
Cache<String,String> = getCache("mycache");
```

These are just known as generic methods http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: This works, but it leads to a warning: "Type safety: The return type Cache<K,V> for getCache(String) from the type ShiroGuavaCacheManager<K,V> needs unchecked conversion to conform to Cache<Object,Object> from the type CacheManager." I can add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"), but what are the implications of doing this?

Comment: It's because you've changed the definition of `getCache` since you no longer define the generic variables inline with the method and they are implicitly `Object`. I think if you try to put the K,V back before  the definition of getCache the compiler will complain that you are redefining K and V (but you can try to be sure). I don't think there's a clean workaround for this, but I'm not a generics expert so maybe someone else can add to this.